# jUnit Error al usar Interface

Tags: java, eclipse, test, pruebas-unitarias, junit

Buenas Tardes tengo un error el error es:

> initializacionError,

Soy nuevo, y tengo un método:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DutyFreeHelperTest.class)
public class DutyFreeHelperTest {

    private ApplicationSettingsRepository applicationSettingsRepository;



    DutyFreeHelper d = new DutyFreeHelper();
    @Test


    @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
    @Test
    public void getDutyFreeFeeValueByGatewayExceptionTest() 
    {
        BigDecimal dutyFreeValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
        dutyFreeValue = DutyFreeHelper.getDutyFreeFeeValueByGateway("cr", applicationSettingsRepository);
        assertNotNull(dutyFreeValue);
        equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));  

    }


    @SuppressWarnings({ "unlikely-arg-type", "unused" })
    @Test 
    public void getDutyFreeFeeValueByGatewayTest() {
        BigDecimal dutyFreeValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
        DutyFreeHelper.getDutyFreeFeeValueByGateway("cr",null);

        equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));  
    }
```

No se que me falta ya he leído muchas cosas, pero estoy aprendiendo solo sobre esto.

```
 public static BigDecimal getDutyFreeFeeValueByGateway(String gateway, ApplicationSettingsRepository applicationSettingsRepository){

    BigDecimal dutyFreeValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
    String wholeConfig;
    String[] arrayConfig;
    List<String> gatewaysWithFreeFee;

    try{

        gatewaysWithFreeFee = Arrays.asList(applicationSettingsRepository.findFirstByKeyName(Constants.DUTY_FREE_FEE).getValue().split(Constants.SEMICOLON));

        if(gatewaysWithFreeFee != null){

             wholeConfig = gatewaysWithFreeFee.stream().filter(x->x.contains(gateway)).findFirst().get();

            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(wholeConfig)){

                arrayConfig = wholeConfig.split(Pattern.quote(Constants.PIPE));
                dutyFreeValue = new BigDecimal(arrayConfig[1].trim());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){

        log.error("DutyFreeHelper | getDutyFreeFeeValueByGateway gateway: {0}  applicationSettingsRepository: {1} | Exception: {2}", gateway, applicationSettingsRepository, ex);
    }

    return dutyFreeValue;
}
```

este es el metodo solo entra en el catch pero no se por que que le falta ya que el applicationsetingrepository viene en null

otra cosa el applicationsetingrepository  es esto

```
   /**
 * Spring Data  repository for the ApplicationSettings entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
@Transactional("quotingtoolTransactionManager")
@PersistenceContext(name = "quotingtoolEntityManagerFactory")
public interface ApplicationSettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<ApplicationSettings, Long> {

    static final String CACHE_PREFIX = "price.";

    public static final String FIND_FIRST_BY_KEY_NAME =  CACHE_PREFIX + "findFirstByKeyName";

    @Cacheable(value = FIND_FIRST_BY_KEY_NAME, key = "#p0")
    ApplicationSettings findFirstByKeyName(String keyName);
}
```

Comment: ¿Acaso no deberías de agregar `ApplicationSettingsRepository` y su implementación a la lista de classes de el contexto de prueba que estás creando?

Comment: si  ApplicationSettingsRepository ApplicationSettingsRepository;    algo como esto es que soy nuevo yo los unit test que hice hace unos mese, creo que no fueron unittest por eso estoy un poco perdido

Comment: entonces ya los agregaste? `@SpringBootTest(classes = DutyFreeHelperTest.class, ApplicationSettingsRepositoryImpl.class)`

Comment: si lo pongo asi me muestr un error de sintaxis token "," , * expected

Comment: sí, porque más de una se ponen con llaves `{DutyFreeHelperTest.class, ApplicationSettingsRepositoryImpl.class}`

Comment: {ponerlo asi me da igualmente error }

Comment: y es que lo puse private static ApplicationSettingsRepository aplication; y lo debugueo y eso me viene null

Comment: @SpringBootTest{classes = DutyFreeHelperTest.class,ApplicationSettingsRepository.class} ejemplo asi lo puse sigue dando eso error

Comment: ApplicationSettingsRepository.class no es una implementación verdad?

Comment: no es una @SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
@Transactional("quotingtoolTransactionManager")
@PersistenceContext(name = "quotingtoolEntityManagerFactory")
public interface ApplicationSettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<ApplicationSettings, Long>

Comment: Podrías haber empezado con que era spring data, prueba con enablerepositories https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database

Comment: Es @SpringBootTest(classes = { DutyFreeHelperTest.class,ApplicationSettingsRepository.class} )

Comment: Te haz fijado que aparece dos veces la anotación @Test sobre el mismo método.